# Javascript post request function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, request

I have the function:

```
const request = require('request')

function test() {
   request.post('endpoint', {
        json: {
              <DATA>
        }
    }, (error, res, body) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);

        }else {
            return body
        }
    }
);
}
```

returns `undefined`, however when I add/ change my code to:

```
function test() {
   request.post('endpoint', {
        json: {
              <DATA>
        }
    }, (error, res, body) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);        
        }else {
            response_code.push(body);
            console.log(body);         //Changed Line
        }
    }
);
}
```

It will print the value I'm expecting to the console.

How do I fix this function it will `return` the value, instead of `undefined`? Appreciate the help.

**Edit:** Both functions will trigger the api successfully, but getting the return value is crucial for the rest of the program.

Comment: The problem with the above is that the `return body` is returning inside the `request.post` callback function i.e. when you call `test()` it calls `request.post()` which then returns immediately with the result of the request happening asynchronously (i.e. some time in the future when the http responds). If you're not attached to callbacks then I would recommend axios with async/await instead as this would simplify things significantly. Alternatively you could use something like `test(callback)` where you would pass in the function that needs the body of the response

Comment: I literally just fixed this as you posted your comment haha, I'll post a solution soon